# IBM AS400/iSeries find which job is blocking a job queue

Tags: queue, ibm-midrange

I'm working on an iSeries with system version 6.1. Some job is keeping other jobs in its queue to process. I know the queue name (PUR1) and see it has an abnormally amount of jobs in it. My understanding is that when a job runs, it moves from it original job queue. So how can I find which job is keeping the others from being processed?

Answer (score 2):

A job is removed from the job queue as part of starting it.  If you have multiple job queues attached to the subsystem, and multiple jobs running in the subsystem, then you have a bit of a challenge.  Take a look at the job queue for each job currently running in the subsystem. One of the first few messages should mention the name of the job queue.